# Spyder IPython console displays output in different lines

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

When we display output of spyder the dataframe gets broken into two lines instead of displaying in one full line as shown in image. Can anyone suggest how to enable this option in Spyder 4.0.1? I have used the following to display the output but it does not work:
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",200) pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYF8R.png)

Comment: Please share what you have done so far

Comment: I have used the following code to extent:
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",200)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

Comment: please share in the question